# Como puedo hacer para devolver un mensaje personalizado en Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

Veréis de vez en cuando necesito borrar un usuario, pero en ocasiones el puede estar en otra tabla ventas y si está en tabla ventas no lo voy a borrar, por eso no he puesto lo del **delete on casacade**.

Tengo esto:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y en la tabla ventas tengo esto:

```
Schema::create('ventas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('fechaCompra');
    });
```

Y las relaciono así:

```
Schema::table('ventas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id_cliente')->unsigned()->after('id');
        $table->foreign('id_cliente')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Cuando intento borrar el usuario me devuelve lo siguiente:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row:

Lo que necesito es si me devuelve esto de alguna manera capturarlo en una variable o en session y mostrar un error personalizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al poner una relacion `ventas -> users` obligas a que debe existir el usuario que registró la venta, por tanto no puedes eliminar a un `usuario[users]` que a registrado una venta, pero si almos quieres capturar esos errores puedes usar `try | catch`

```
    use Exception;
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //$e -> contiene el error y toda sus detalles
        return "Ocurrieron errores";
    }
```

Comment: Hola al final lo que hice fue buscar en la tabla ventas si existe el id del usuario y si existe devuelvo error y de lo contrario si lo borro. Pero muchas gracias. me lo guardo por si me vuelvo a topar con algo parecido. muchas gracias.